# map_server to save map from nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid published by the Google cartographer ROS API?

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using Google cartographer ROS API to generate a map. Is it possible to use ROS map_server with this to save the map using rosrun map_server map_server mymap.yaml or retrieve the map using nav_msgs/GetMap?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295813/map_server-to-save-map--from-nav_msgs/occupancygrid-published-by-the-google-cartographer-ros-api?/) by [kllysin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35780/kllysin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I find the problem about "waiting for the map" when I use map saver to generate a map.I think it's possible to use the command you said above.But my problem is that it's always waiting for the map and there's no map generated.

---

Originally posted by [fgy4010](https://answers.ros.org/users/36547/fgy4010/) with karma: 16 on 2018-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0